# Printing from an array in PHP from a GET variable?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This code gets an array of 2 items from a Database. I want to set the `$_GET` variable values based on that array.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
// connect to DB
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'article');
if (!$db_selected){
    die("can't use article : " .mysqli_error());
}
// extract databases table to PHP array
$query = "SELECT * FROM `articles`";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$article_array = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $artic = $row['name'];
    $amount = $row['quantity'];
    $article_array[$artic] = $amount;
}
// test array
//print_r($article_array); ---> works!

// print the array in the pos of id
if(isset($_GET['id']){
    echo 'id is: '.$article_array[$_GET['id'];
} else {
    echo 'soemthing is wrong';
}   
?>
```

The above is what I tried: the url `localhost/hello.php?id=1` should retrieve the variable id and set it in the `$_GET` variable. However, the last echo statement does not work as expected.

Comment: DId you build the indexes of the array using the records ID? If not, you will not get the result you have in your thoughts. A standard array uses default index 0,1,2,3,4,5 etc.

Comment: There isn't enough code here to see why it is failing. Can you show us the results of a `var_dump($article_array)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a working example:

Link to: page.php?color=2

page.php

```
$colours = array();
$colours[] = 'Red';
$colours[] = 'White';
$colours[] = 'Blue';

if(isset($_GET['color']){
    echo 'Selected colour is: '.$colours[$_GET['color'];
} else {
    echo 'Something is wrong';
}
```

Should output "Selected colour is Blue";

Comment: Well I tried to use your method but it seems like I did something wrong because its not working for me.